# How to get filtered statistics in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

After I had great pleasure with the simple implementation of filters in the admin-on-rest List View, I would now like to have a similar view, which does not show the individual posts in a table or as cards but aggregated statistics related to the filter. 
For example: Filter all users by male gender. The statistics should then be based on the men, e. g. a histogram with an age distribution.

Is it possible to modify a [Custom Iterator](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#using-a-custom-iterator) in this way? If not, how can I achieve my goal? Can someone give me a jump-start?

Answer (score 1):

You could indeed use a Custom Iterator, however you'll only receive a page of resources which may not be ideal to generate statistics.

If you want statistics on **all** the data targeted by the filters, you have two options:

- declare a new resource for statistics allowing the same filters and generate the statistic on server side. Then, use a Custom Iterator to display them nicely
- create a custom route for statistics and do what you would do in a classic React app without using aor